# why @TableGenerator(name="tabgen1",table="cID",allocationSize=1) create a new table

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, derby

In my small project i will create 4 table, 2 of this table have One-to-One relations:

```
@Entity @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true) @SuppressWarnings("serial") public class Creation implements Serializable {
@TableGenerator(name="tabgen1",table="cID",allocationSize=1,pkColumnName="ColumnName",pkColumnValue="ColVal",valueColumnName="valCOLName")
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,generator="tabgen1")
@Id
    private Long UserId;
```

and second Entity is

```
@Entity @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true) public class Worker implements Serializable {

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Creation creation;

@Id
@TableGenerator(name="tabgen2",table="WID",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,generator="tabgen2")
private Long WorkerId;
```

and it create more tables...., but i want safe generated walues in one of my 4 tables, its real or i make some mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but specifying `AUTO` and `generator` at the same time is illogical. `AUTO` means that the ORM should pick the generation strategy it finds the most appropriate. And generator forces it to use a specific generator. So they're contradictory.

Use `TABLE` instead of `AUTO`, since you want the ID to be generated using a table generator.

Comment: So you're using a table generator, but are surprised it uses a table? Use a sequence generator, and use a specific sequence for every entity. AUTO with Derby probably uses a sequence generator, but uses the same sequence for every entity.

Comment: like this:
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")

Comment: and when i am using like above, after added a new row i will get an Exeption: **org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequens value?**

Comment: Did you define the sequence in the database?

Comment: sory but i dont know how to define the sequence in the db derby

Comment: i will create a query:
**CREATE SEQUENCE USERID
AS BIGINT
START WITH 3000000000; **
and netbeans say : **Error code -1, the position of SQL X0Y68: Sequence 'USERID' already exists.**